# My hotbar disappeared

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing Minecraft Window 10 version on a MacBook. I just finished playing a mini game on a server. After I teleported back to the lobby, I realized my hotbar is gone! I googled, and tried every single solution I could find, but none of them work.

PS, I tried <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>; I tried to find something in the settings that can turn it on, but it didn't help at all.

Comment: You're playing MCBE on a Mac? That's amazing! How did you do it?

Comment: Also, check your resource packs. Does it also happen without any enabled? What about after restarting MCBE?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade SE. Are you sure it isn't a server functionality? Hotbar may not be useful in a server lobby, so the creators of this server may have made it disappear (not sure but I guess it's possible). Have you tried to launch a solo map or launch another mini-game?